# Azure Cosmos Mongo API version 3.2 to 3.6 upgrade

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We have to upgrade Azure Cosmos Mongo API from version 3.2 to 3.6. Could anyone suggest steps to migrate all the Database and collections from 3.2 to 3.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my researching,you can't upgrade 3.2 to 3.6 directly with cosmos db mongo api.However,you could do the data transfer. Please get an idea of [Azure Data Factory Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) which supports [cosmos db mongo api connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api).

[image]

[image]

Or you could try the [DMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-mongodb-cosmos-db?toc=/azure/cosmos-db/toc.json) following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data).

Comment: This does seem to be an option now - https://github.com/LuisBosquez/azure-cosmos-db-api-for-mongodb-misc-docs/blob/master/upgrade-v36.md

Answer (score 1):

**CosmosDB with Mongo server version 3.2 can be upgraded to version 3.6 by raising new support request in Support+troubleshooting section:**

```
Issue type: Technical
Resource: your-cosmos-db
Problem type: MongoDB
Problem subtype: Mongo protocol upgrade assistance (Migrating your mongo account to 3.6)
```

[Screenshot of New support request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGgPl.png)

**Microsoft description in the "Solutions" section of New support request:**

Updating Mongo DB 3.2 to 3.6
All new accounts provisioned using Azure Portal will have the option to provision with server version 3.6.
For existing accounts a support ticket to update is required and the update will change the server version. While generally 3.6 is compatible with 3.2, it is recommended a customer provision a new account through the portal and select the Mongo DB server version 3.6 to try it out with their application on a dev or qa instance before considering updating the account backing any production workload.

See https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/39654955-upgrading-existing-accounts-from-mongodb-server-ve about "upgrade 3.2 to 3.6" feature in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

This has shifted over time but there are now fairly clear instructions[0] about how to do this in a simple self-service manner in the portal.

[0] https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/upgrade-your-server-version-from-3-2-to-3-6-for-azure-cosmos-db-api-for-mongodb/#how-to-upgrade-my-account-on-the-azure-portal